# Joda DateTimeFormatter giving a mixture of languages

Tags: java, time, jodatime

This is super weird.

I'm using a Joda Time DateTimeFormatter, giving the format

```
EEE MMM d, yyyy h:mm a 'UTC'ZZ
```

and it's printing

```
mié may 29, 2013 5:15 PM UTC-06:00
```

Which seems to be a mixture of Spanish and English.

```
    formatLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM d, yyyy h:mm a 'UTC'ZZ"), dateTime)



public static String formatLocalDateTime(final DateTimeFormatter formatter, final DateTime dateTime) {
    if (dateTime == null) {
        return "";
    }
    DateTimeFormatter f = formatter.withLocale(LocaleUtils.toLocale("es_US"));
    f = f.withZone(getTimeZone());

    return f.print(dateTime);
}
```

I'm completely lost. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your Locale - you are getting the correct formatting for "es_US" - see, for example, http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/es-US/

If you are expecting US English, use "en_US"
If what you want is Spanish (Spain), use "es_ES"

The list of Locales is at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html

Edit - What you are seeing are the 'short' Day of Week and Month of Year.
If you want the 'long' versions, which are both in Spanish in es_US, use the format

```
"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a 'UTC'ZZ"
```

which will yield

> miércoles mayo 29, 2013 5:15 PM UTC-06:00